# PHP - alerts with inputs are displayed at the wrong time

Tags: php, alerts

I am new at PHP and working on my first college assignment. I have an issue that I can't fix.  I have alerts on the index.php page that should only appear when the user attempts to submit the data for confirmation and the data is missing or incorrect. Currently, when the page loads, the alerts work just as they should and only appear if the user attempts to "calculate" the page with missing or incorrect data. After the calculations, the user clicks the "confirm" button which takes them to the second page confirm.php .. from there the user should be able to click "return" and go back to the first page. This works as it should but now I have alerts next to the input boxes when the user returns to the first page.  They should not be displaying at this time.  I don't know how to correct this. Help please?

```html
<?php
/**
 * Student: Sherrie Teague
 * Server-Side Programming
 * Date: 2/6/2019
 * HW2 - Quote
 */


/*
 * Course : Server-Side Programming
 * Student: Sherrie Teague
 * Assignment: HW2 - Quote
 * Date : 2/6/2019
*/

// get the data from the form
$sales_price = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'sales_price', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$discount_percent = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'discount_percent',FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$total_price = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'total_price', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);


if( isset( $_POST['confirmSubmit'] )) {
    echo 'Validation Error';
    // or store it in a variable and post later
    $validation_error = 'Validation Error';
}

$sales_valid = true;
$sales_priceError = '';
if ($sales_price === FALSE) {
    $sales_priceError = 'Sales price must be a valid amount';
    $sales_valid = false;
} else if ($sales_price < 1.0) {
    $sales_priceError = 'Sales price must be greater than 0';
    $sales_valid = false;
}

$discount_valid = true;
$discount_percentError = '';
// validate discount_percent
if ($discount_percent === FALSE) {
    $discount_percentError = 'Discount percent must be a valid amount';
    $discount_valid = false;
} else if ($discount_percent < 1.0) {
    $discount_percentError = 'Discount percent must be greater than 0';
    $discount_valid = false;
}


// calculate the discount and the discounted price
$discount_amount = $sales_price * $discount_percent / 100;
$total_price = $sales_price - $discount_amount;

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Quote</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quote.css">
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <h1>Price Quotation</h1>
    <form id="priceForm" name="priceForm" method="post" action=''>
        <label for="sales_price">Sales Price </label>
        <input type="text" id="sales_price" name="sales_price" required
               value="<?php echo $sales_price; ?>"/>
        <?php if (!empty($sales_priceError)) : ?>
            <span style="color:red;background-color: white">
                    <?php echo $sales_priceError; ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="discount_percent">Discount Percent </label>
        <input type="text" id="discount_percent" name="discount_percent" required
               value="<?php echo $discount_percent; ?>"/>
        <?php if (!empty($discount_percentError)) : ?>
            <span style="color:red;background-color: white">
                    <?php echo $discount_percentError; ?>
                </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <p class="discount">Discount Amount <?php echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$' . number_format($discount_amount, 2); ?></p>
        <p class="total">Total Price <?php echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$' . number_format($total_price, 2); ?></p>
        <input type="submit" class=inline name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Calculate"/>
    </form>

    <!--     <form id="confirmForm" name="confirmForm" method="post" action="confirm.php">-->
    <form id="confirmForm" name="confirmForm" method="post" action="<?php echo (( $sales_valid && $discount_valid ) ? 'confirm.php' : ''); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="sales_price" name="sales_price" value="<?php echo $sales_price ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="discount_amount" name="discount_amount" value="<?php echo $discount_amount ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="total_price" name="total_price" value="<?php echo $total_price ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" class= inline name="confirmSubmit" id="confirmSubmit" value="Confirm"/>
    </form>

    <div>
        <p> Enter price and discount amount and click Calculate</p>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is because your form handlers are outside of if( isset( $_POST['confirmSubmit'] )), so they are always executed.

Comment: you need to  wrap all the post stuff in `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ ...form processing code..}` this way if the form is not submitted none of it runs.  I wouldn't use `confirmSubmit` or the presence of a button.  If you trigger that form with JavaScript you will find that the submit button is not included in the request.  (well last I checked like 5 years ago)

Comment: Thank you. The assignment requires 2 buttons on the first page .. a "calculate" and a "confirm". The "confirm" directs the user to a second page.

Comment: And, unfortunately, I can't fix my problem without more specific help. This is the first assignment and we've only had a few lectures.  It is all trial and error for me right now, until I get a stronger grasp of this language. I don't quite know what my "form handlers" include or where I would need to place them to be correctly placed within the if (isset ($POST ... ).